# Adblocker blocks ajax urls containing keywords ad. Is there anyway to handle this instead of changing the url

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter, adblock

Adblocker blocks the urls like

http://localhost/project1/advertiser/users/get_user_listing/

Since it contains the keyword advertiser. I have so many urls and ajax calls contains this keywords. Is there anyway to escape this blocker?

**Note: Changing my folder name is not possible since it is used in so many places in my code.**

Comment: Yet another example of how adblockers use a scorched earth approach that ends up breaking web pages...

Comment: Best to just use find and replace in your code to change the directory name.

Comment: Ok thanks.............

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved easily by following these steps.

1. While firefox is the active window press Ctrl + Shift + V, this will open the "Blockable items window"
2. In the window you will list of address and type of files being
   recieved from them.
3. Find the link there that you want to unblock, right click and choose
   "Disable filter". Reload and see if it works fine after that.

Comment: Thanks:) 
The actual problem is, how can we do this without the user intervention? ie Website Users may not be knowing about this problem.  Is there anyway from a developers perspective?

Comment: if users of your website are using adblock AND resources that are loaded by your website contain address including word like "ads" or any such thing, there is not much you can do about it

Comment: you can of course add a message on your website asking users to disable adblock, they may or may not disable it

Comment: That is already done. But checking solutions other than changing the folder path if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you can do about it, but neither is perfect:

1) Go to the [EasyList](https://forums.lanik.us/viewforum.php?f=64) forums, tell them that Adblock is effectively breaking your site and request a @@ exception rule added to EasyList. This is easier and faster than you may think. But keep in mind that there are multiple adblockers out there, and not all of them use the same filter lists. (And some use no filter lists at all). So if you want to prevent this happening in every adblocker out there, rather than just the top 1 or 2, the task of asking for filter exceptions can be time consuming.

2) Use .htaccess to create an alias or subdomain for the directory/folder that's being blocked which doesn't contain the word "advertiser".

Still, I'm not sure why you can't do a find/replace across all your site files for the directory name. How hard can this be?

Comment: Thanks @Bangkokian.  So many modules referring this advertiser module is completed. So its very hard to change that. As you told, in order to do with .htaccess, The adblocker is blocking from the client side itself. So the request doen not reach at the server side in order to replace the url.